# Are race usage statistics available to the public?

Tags: starcraft-2

Previously in the beta I heard Blizzard was making balance changes based on the usage % and win % of each race.  I have no idea if this was true, but the idea intrigued me. Are there statistics available to the public?

I am very curious what the usage statistics for each race are.

Comment: Smells like a dup

Comment: If you could find me an existing post (I couldn't) I would be grateful

Comment: I think it was due to [this question regarding some races having an advantage over others](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/do-some-races-have-major-advantages-over-others-in-starcraft-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used http://sc2ranks.com you could figure out which races are played in which division and which country by playing around with the filters and seeing how many hits you get back. Not every player is covered by this site but the good majority are.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You don't even have to do the filtering yourself: http://sc2ranks.com/stats/league/all/1/all