# How do you build a Load Out for Modern Warfare

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I'm not looking for a list of Load Outs that are common, or a description of what menu's to go through, but rather for an understanding of which parts of the game are Synergistic and compliment.

- What Perks/Guns/Attachments naturally work well together?
- When making a choice, what important things should I consider?
- How are these choices potentially affected by gameplay type or map pool ?
- How does level play a role?

Comment: So when I wrote this question I was hoping for an answer that looked something like this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4016  A discussion of what works well with other things and why, not just a list of load outs.

Comment: were you still interested in this?  I could write up a more descriptive answer if you'd like

Comment: @Aardvark I am always interested in better answers.  If you have one I would love to hear it.

Comment: Tzenes, I'd love to help... I'll draft up a small book on the synergies between perks and post here within the next day or two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the major considerations i make when creating a load out is "What do i want to do with this load out?" then i pick and choose perks that best suit that end goal.

Here is an example of a load out that i used to answer the need "I want to run around like a nut and knife people like crazy.":

- USP + Tac Knife
- Riot Shield
- Flash Bangs
- Marathon Pro
- Lightweight
- Commando Pro

The synergy here is strong, and its also quite annoying to the opponent. I'll go over the synergy even tho I fear it's quite obvious.

First off Lightweight gets you moving much quicker, the Pro for lightweight doesn't really help much in this load out, but its always a bonus.

Moving quicker is nice since you want to focus on knifing people with this load out, which brings me to the USP + Tac Knife. This allows you to knife much faster and MUCH more frequently. Many times I've been able to sneak into a room and kill off 3+ people because of being able to knife so quickly. Without it maybe 1 or 2 people before they start to react and take me down.

The riot shield is great for fleeing from an opponent, as it greatly reduces the surface area of your body that is available to shoot. As well as allowing you to provide a distraction to your opponents for your teammates if you pull it to the front and block for them.

Flash bangs are always useful, even more so when you need to get close to the opponent. (to knife them)

Marathon pro is important because it allows you to run forever, which is very important when you have to be close to kill, and also makes those pesky ladders not so pesky.

Commando pro lets you take that swipe much sooner and greatly increases your lethality when focusing on knife killing. and the pro, removing falling damage is amazing when you are running around like a nut trying to avoid getting shot. Jumping out a window without fear of death is a nice thing to have.

So, there ya go, the focus of the load out is to keep moving get close and stab a lot. Every item in the load out furthers that goal to some extent, as well as providing a little bit of utility to help the team if needed.

Comment: If only I could get you to do more break downs like this; well done.

Comment: If you are going for speed, the riot shield will slow you down.  Pick up a sniper rifle or something lighter to be as fast as possible.

Comment: In my playing, the benefits of having a shield vs having a light weapon to move a little bit faster. The shield is way more effective and preventing damage than the small speed boost.

Comment: This is a 'killer' combination. Will totally try it out. Don't have the Tac Knife yet, but working towards it.

Answer (score 4):

**What Perks/Guns/Attachments naturally work well together?**

Lightweight Pro + Ninja Pro + Marathon Pro + UMP with silencer is the best if you want to go silent and move quickly around the map.

Sleight of Hand Pro + Stopping Power Pro + Steady Aim plus a baretta .cal or an intervention is the perfect sniper "class". You need the stopping power to deal extra damage indifferent of the body part you are aiming at.

**When making a choice, what important things should I consider?**

What type of map are you playing, what type of game and really what type of player are you (sniper, stealth, commando, defender, etc)

Don't worry about players with higher levels than you, trust me, in this game levels aren't direct proportional with player skill.

**How are these choices potentially affected by gameplay type or map pool ?**

I've answered partially above, all in all it depends on your skill and the weapon you feel the most comfortable with. If you are a sniper and you feel that the intervention is your gun no matter the map or game you will be good at it.

**How does level play a role?**

Levels are there for getting upgrades and camos. Also you get attachments by using a specific type of weapons. You get your perks upgraded by using a specific perk over and over.

In any case to get to upgrade some attachments faster use the default classes that have the goodies unlocked. E.G Tactical knife can be unlocked by playing with the First Recon class, it's a short way to get it done.

---

**EDIT**: First Build: The UMP has the best recoil in the game in my honest opinion, you aim smoother and there is a very slim chance that your cross-hair will wiggle too much. The Perk combination is obvious move faster and be undetected. Ninja Pro silences your footsteps.

Second Build: A sniper rifle has a high recoil so you need to reload fast to make each shot count. With Steady Aim you can keep your breath for an extensive period of time. Stopping Power Pro will enhance the damage dealt by half i believe, so even if you hit the body for example it will be a a kill and not a hit marker.

I forgot the secondary weapons, never used them that much, but if you want to be sure you get the guy before you restock on your primary get a shotgun, more specifically the Spas-12.

Comment: Could you explain more about why the two builds you have there work well together?

Comment: This is a great explanation. Ninja Pro sounds great...need to earn it.

Answer (score 3):

To make the most out of class setups you really need to pay attention to weapon damage vs perks. For example, the UMP's damage effectively makes Stopping Power useless. With or without stopping power it is the same # of bullets to kill. The same thing goes for the WA2000.

Similarly, think about the rate of fire of the weapon. The higher it is, the less use for stopping power, since it will generally only change the number of bullets to kill by a few. Ex: the f2000. The ROF is so high that the one or two bullets less it takes to kill with SP is hardly noticeable, since you'll already be shooting so many.

In terms of gametype synergies with loadouts, if you play domination, have a marathon+lightweight class. Since one of the keys to dom is getting B early and holding it, start with the fastest moving class you can to get there. Depending on the side you come from, you'll have as much as 4 seconds before any other player can possibly make it there, which is half the capture time. Do this with a buddy and you might have B before your team takes the closest flag.

Also, consider your ability to stay alive. I generally live long enough that having enough ammo actually matters, so I use scavenger pro quite a bit. If you end up only getting a few kills for each death, something like Slight of Hand will benefit you much more.

You should also think about using One Man Army if you're going for the higher killstreaks. Have three classes with the same weapon, OMA as first perk, and then Stopping Power, HardLine, and Danger Close as the different tier 2 perks. Use stopping power until you're 2 kills before a killstreak, switch to hardline, get one kill, switch to danger close and make the killstreak work better, then back to Stopping Power for more kills.